# Is there a way to restart the application instead of having it restart the last activity after a crash?

Tags: java, android-activity, android

Since I store certain information that is necessary in my Application class, when a user encounters a crash, sometimes they encounter two crashes since the last activity needs information stored in the application class.

Activity A  >> Activity B (needs info from Application class) >> Activity C

Crash occurs on C >> Application tries to open Activity B >> Crash occurs on B because it needs info from the Application class (this has been reset)

I want to avoid this, so I was hoping that there is someway I can restart the whole application after a crash instead of the activity.

Comment: Frankly, you need to handle that case anyway. Speaking from experience, you'll run into that scenario eventually even without the application crashing. If the app is in the background for a significant period of time, or enough memory is taken up by other apps while yours is in the background, your application (and open activities) will have their state saved and will be killed off for restoration later. At which point, any data you've stored in your Application class will need to be reloaded.

Comment: Instead of fixing the symptoms, fix the problem : why is your app crashing in Activity C ? Also, how do you handle saving state during your Activities lifecycle ?

Comment: If anyone one of your "internal" activities finds it has been created without necessary previous setup, it should use an Intent to redirect to your normal "front door" activity.

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution of many but I'll put it here as an option:

You could use `startActivityForResult()` and when you handle the error in Activity C, `finish()` it with a result code that you recognize as a crash and handle things appropriately in the `onActivityResult()` of Activity B.

**[Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)**

Comment: yea, i thought of this, but i was hoping for an easier solution

Answer (score 2):

The nicest solution is to handle the case in which you do not have the necessary information at any activity (in your case Activity B).

You should check at the onCreate method whether you have the information or not, and act in consecuence:

- Finishing the activity to go back to your activity A
- Launching another activity
- Asking the user for feedback
- Any other action you think fits best

There may be more than one reason explaining why you don't have that information (as other answers point out), so in my opinion the best option is to handle the case.

Comment: i think i may end up just doing this. it is the right way of going about this.

Answer (score 1):

Untested theory, just spitballing.

Could you attach yourself as a default exception handler, and start calling `finish()` on the open activities? If you can finish all your activities, wouldn't that effectively shut down the app, and reopening it would be as if it were getting launched fresh?

Comment: don't quite understand. can you please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't keep any state in the Application object. Keep it in the Bundle you receive in the onCreate(). Eventually use onSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceState to save/restore state.